# JQuery, capture url as variable

Tags: jquery, cookies

witrh Jquery I'm looking at trying to capture the current URL of current page and storing it as a variable but also trimming and adding part of a new address.

Explained in the code.

```
if (!!$.cookie('ppc_campaign') || $.cookie('organic')) {
    if(window.location.contains("/lpt/") || ("/lp/")) {
        $ppc_url = 'capture url here but remove everything before the ? character and concatenate https://newurl.com at the start';
        $.cookie('ppc_campaign', $ppc_url, { expires: 28, path: '/' });
    }
    else {
        $.cookie('organic', 'https://anotheraddress.com/split?campaign=organic', { expires: 28, path: '/' });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure jQuery style:

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
```

The location object also has other properties, like host, hash, protocol, and pathname.